# How can I store custom object/attribute in an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm refactoring an old table that has one column with edittext.

In order to accomplish the new requirement, everytime that the content of EditText has changed I need to validate against the old value.

Then I want to store the:

- Old value or
- A key to retrieve the old value from an array

as an additional attribute for the `EditText`.

I know that I can create a custom EditText with my new attributes (but it will be maybe a major refactor).
There is a way to avoid that?
Something like custom attributes of html?

Many thanks

Comment: You could use `setTag` to store an additional object to an `EditText`

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a bit of a hack but you could probably use the edittext's (or any view objects) tag property and set the old value to the tag. Compare with the tag or update the tag if necessary.